# Get text from Input field in Unity3D with C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input-field, unity3d-gui

I'm trying to get a text inside an inputField in `Unity3D` with `C#`.

I've placed an inputField in my editor, renamed and tagged in: **Username_field**.

My question is: How i can get the text inside the `InputField` **Username_field** in a `C#` script?

Comment: I've been able to do it with InputField.value. Example: String s = myInputField.value  to get the value or myInputField.value = "Test" to set the value.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Attach below monobehaviour script to your InputField gameObject:

```
public class test : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start ()
    {
        var input = gameObject.GetComponent<InputField>();
        var se= new InputField.SubmitEvent();
        se.AddListener(SubmitName);
        input.onEndEdit = se;

        //or simply use the line below, 
        //input.onEndEdit.AddListener(SubmitName);  // This also works
    }

    private void SubmitName(string arg0)
    {
        Debug.Log(arg0);
    }
}
```

See also below animation:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use the "On Value Change" or "End Edit" event of the [InputField](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-InputField.html).

The Unity3D documentation provides more detail on how to use a UnityEvent: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityEvents.html

Alternatively, you should also be able to access the Text using the [Text property of the Text control](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Text.html) that your InputField is attached to.

Comment: In Unity 2017 you have to use the text component of the InputField (`String myText = myInputField.GetComponent<InputField>().text;`) instead of the text component of the child text, otherwise an e.g. password field will only return asterisks (*). There's a warning about it [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-InputField.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
public InputField betInput;
void Start () {
    betInput.onEndEdit.AddListener(delegate { inputBetValue(betInput); });
}
public void inputBetValue(InputField userInput)
{
    betValue = int.Parse(userInput.text);
    Debug.Log(userInput.text);
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeF1a.png //This is unity Picture where you select method.
Also worth checking out https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/text-input