# Cannot set text on InputField

Tags: unity-game-engine

I try to set text in InputField, but it's dont change correctly. I can see new value on text field in editor, but not for user. After lose/set focus on element text field is update.
Code is so simple that i dont know what to do.

```
public InputField Text;
private volatile string _oldValue;

public void OnTextChange(string text)
{
    if (_oldValue == Text.text)
        return;
    _oldValue = Text.text + "1";
    Text.text = _oldValue;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate, see if this post helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28273062/get-text-from-input-field/28273568#28273568

Comment: Thx, David. I'll try it today, but is this correct behaviour? What should i do, if i want to catch event every time when text changed?