# NullReferenceException when trying to get text from inputfield

Tags: text, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception, input-field

I am new to unity and want to get a value from a input text field. I found this question 
[Get text from Input field in Unity3D with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28273062/get-text-from-input-field), but when I execute it the same error always appear: NullReferenceExcpetion : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
It seems like a stupid mistake and I tried everything but can't seem to fix it.
My code:

```
void Start () {
    var input = gameObject.GetComponent<InputField>();
    input.onEndEdit.AddListener(SubmitName);

}

private void SubmitName(string arg0)
{
    Debug.Log(arg0);
}
```

I tried putting `InputField input`; before the start function and erasing `var` but still no luck.
If anyone can help me with this problem it would be much appreciated.
Pictures of where my scripts are attached at the moment.
[image]

[image]

Comment: you should include the script only on the canvas OR on the InputField. I would add it just to the canvas, so you have an element which will take control of his children (InputField and other UI elements). But please drag the `InputField` from the `Hierarchy` to the empty field at the bottom of the inspector where you can read **None (Input Field)**

Comment: Oky thank you so much the input field could not be dragged but I created a new one and everything is in order. Thanks alot.

Comment: I just have one question the output is InputField(UnityEngine.UI.InputField) and not what I entered in the inputfield.

Comment: I really don't know what exactly is inside your script because you still didn't post it. But looks to me like you forgot to import the library for the ui `using UnityEngine.UI;` in the header so you can access the ui elements just by their name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is nearly correct, if you [have a look at the documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.InputField-onValueChange.html), you have to call your method with `function` before calling the method name. It looks to me like you are mixing `c#` and `JS`, here is the `js function:

```
public class Example {
    public var mainInputField;
    public function Start() {
        // Adds a listener to the main input field 
        // and invokes a method when the value changes.
        mainInputField.onValueChange.AddListener(function() {
            ValueChangeCheck();
        });
    }
    // Invoked when the value of the text field changes.
    public function ValueChangeCheck() {
        Debug.Log("Value Changed");
    }
}
```

**the `c#` solution:**

```
public class MenuController : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]
    InputField inputText;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        inputText.onValueChange.AddListener(delegate {
            DebugInput();
        });
    }

    private void DebugInput(){
        Debug.Log ("Input: " + inputText);
    }
}
```

**My Hierarchie looks like this:**

I created a `Canvas` and inserted an `InputField` inside it. The script with the code inside is attached to the `Canvas` and the `InputField` connected to the `[SerializeField]` inside the script in the `Canvas`.

---

I would recommend you to make your `InputField` a class variable, so you can access it easier later. Furthermore you should just create a `[SerializeField]` for your `InputField` so you can drag it to your script. This might avoid some mistakes too.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply but I still get the same error of the Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I added my script to the InputField.

Comment: Have you added the `InputField` inside your canvas and did you connect it with your script by dragging the `InputField` into the scripts placeholder inside the `inspector`?

Comment: Yes I did both and my script is attached to the text of the InputField.

Comment: I just tried to but the script only on the InputField but it still gave the same error.

Comment: I explained it in my post how I setup everything. If this won't work, could you please make a screenshot on selecting the `UIElement` with the script so we can see where the problem is

Comment: Oky I post the screenshots to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Change InputField(TMP) to InputField(Legacy)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).