# How Can Get String From Players On Play Mode With Unity

Tags: c#, android, string, unity-game-engine

In mobile,
I am asking a question to player and i want answer my question. But how can open the answer box or something else. I mean the player click asnwer button after that opening keyboard and write his answer and click send button and  i of course save the answer. I dont know what is the textbox in unity how can i do it. I am working on C#

Comment: You are looking for Input Field : http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-InputField.html . This is UI component

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28273062/get-text-from-input-field-in-unity3d-with-c-sharp

Comment: I don't think this question falls within scope of StackOverflow http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve please rework your question and clarify what you're asking with some example code showing what you've attempted so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Input field, it works on all devices. http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-InputField.html

If you're using unity 4.6 or above, you have to use a canvas along with it.