# Unity: get text from Input field

Tags: unity-game-engine

So, I am new to unity and I am trying to follow a tutorial, In the tutorial, they are trying to get the text of an input field however when I try it I get the error:

> 'GameObject' does not contain a definition for 'text' and no accessible extension method 'text' accepting a first argument of type 'GameObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

My code looks like this:

```
[SerializeField] private GameObject UsernameInput;
...
Debug.Log(UsernameInput.text);
```

I have added my `UsernameInput` like so:
[MyImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKlHR.png)

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28273062/get-text-from-input-field-in-unity3d-with-c-sharp) but it doesn't help.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gameObject does not contain a field named 'text'. Where you want to access is to the field 'text' of the Component of type InputField.

So, in your code, you should call it as following:

```
    Debug.Log(UsernameInput.GetComponent<InputField>().text);
```

I let you [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Components.html) a hyperlink to the documentation about Components in Unity which talks about what they are.

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped me greatly and saved me massive amounts of time. :)